# Displaying data on first activity that is set in the second activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

The thing is I have a dashboard which will display data for 6 production lines, and the progress will be viewed in simply `textviews`.

However, the data for the textviews are coming from a series of IF statements and calculations which are performed on another activity.

When I run the app because the dashboard is trying to read data before it has been set by the second `activity`, there is null pointers which is understandable as I haven't got the chance to even get to the second `activity` yet.

To compromise I had to set the IF statements on the dashboard to buttons, however, this is hindering the usability of my app and I would like the data to automatically refresh on the dashboard without pressing a button.

On the second activity I am saving the values to shared preferences and then on the dashboard I am getting the shared preference and setting it to the textviews but still getting nulls as the dashboard is the first screen.

**Line Details Java: (Home button to return to dashboard):**

```
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            if (spinnerSelection == null || spinnerSelection2 == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Data Input Error");
                builder.setMessage("Line S2 Data has not been entered yet!");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S1") && spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
                if (actualshippersnum > optimum20) {
                    plus20 = (int) (actualshippersnum - optimum20);
                    editor.putInt("Key1", plus20);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S1 ahead by: " + (plus20) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum20) {
                    minus20 = (int) (optimum20 - actualshippersnum);
                    editor.putInt("Key2", minus20);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S1 behind by: " + (minus20) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum20) {
                    editor.putInt("Key3", percentageActual20);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S1 is on target at!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S1") && spinnerSelection2.equals("30")) {
                if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                    builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum30) {
                    plus30 = (int) (actualshippersnum - optimum30);
                    editor.putInt("Key 4", plus30);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S1 ahead by: " + (plus30) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum30) {
                    minus30 = (int) (optimum30 - actualshippersnum);
                    editor.putInt("Key 5", minus30);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S1 behind by: " + (minus30) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum30) {
                    editor.putInt("Key 6", percentageActual30);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S1 is on target!", +Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            if (spinnerSelection == null || spinnerSelection2 == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Data Input Error");
                builder.setMessage("Line S2 Data has not been entered yet!");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S2") && spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
                if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                    builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum20) {
                    plus20 = (int) (actualshippersnum - optimum20);
                    editor.putInt("Key 7", plus20);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S2 ahead by: " + (plus20) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum20) {
                    minus20 = (int) (optimum20 - actualshippersnum);
                    editor.putInt("Key 8", minus20);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S2 behind by: " + (minus20) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum20) {
                    editor.putInt("Key 9", percentageActual20);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S2 is on target at!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S2") && spinnerSelection2.equals("30")) {
                if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                    builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum30) {
                    plus30 = (int) (actualshippersnum - optimum30);
                    editor.putInt("Key 10", plus30);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S2 ahead by: " + (plus30) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum30) {
                    minus30 = (int) (optimum30 - actualshippersnum);
                    editor.putInt("Key 11", minus30);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S2 behind by: " + (minus30) + " shippers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum30) {
                    editor.putInt("Key 12", percentageActual30);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S2 is on target!", +Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            if (spinnerSelection == null || spinnerSelection2 == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Data Input Error");
                builder.setMessage("Line S3 Data has not been entered yet!");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S3")) {
                if (spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
                    //HAVENT FILLED INTO DECOVIEW - 20
                    if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                        builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                        builder.setCancelable(true);

                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else
                    if (actualshippersnum > optimum20) {
                        plus20 = (int) (actualshippersnum - optimum20);
                        editor.putInt("Key 13", plus20);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S3 ahead by: " + (plus20)+ " shippers" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum20) {
                        minus20 = (int) (optimum20 - actualshippersnum);
                        editor.putInt("Key 14", minus20);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S3 behind by: " + (minus20)+ " shippers" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum20) {
                        editor.putInt("Key 15", percentageActual20);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S3 is on target!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else if (spinnerSelection2.equals("30")) {

                    //HAVENT FILLED INTO DECOVIEW - 30
                    if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                        builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                        builder.setCancelable(true);

                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    } else
                    if (actualshippersnum > optimum30) {
                        plus30 = (int) (actualshippersnum - optimum30);
                        editor.putInt("Key 16", plus30);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S3 ahead by: " + (plus30)+ " shippers" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum30) {
                        minus30 = (int) (optimum30 - actualshippersnum);
                        editor.putInt("Key 17", minus30);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S3 behind by: " + (minus30)+ " shippers" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum30) {
                        editor.putInt("Key 18", percentageActual30);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Line S3 is on target!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Dashboard Java: (On Resume)**

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int getKey1, getKey2, getKey3, getKey4, getKey5, getKey6, getKey7, getKey8, getKey9, getKey10, getKey11, getKey12, getKey13, getKey14, getKey15, getKey16,getKey17, getKey18;

    if (spinnerSelection == null || spinnerSelection2 == null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
        builder.setTitle("Data Input Error");
        builder.setMessage("No SP found!");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S1") && spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
        if (actualshippersnum > optimum20) {
            getKey1 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key1", plus20);
            bar4.setText(getKey1);
        } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum20) {
            getKey2 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key2", minus20);
            bar4.setText(getKey2);
        } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum20) {
            getKey3 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key3", percentageActual20);
            bar4.setText(getKey3);
    }


        else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S1") && spinnerSelection2.equals("30")) {
        if (actualshippersnum == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
            builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
            builder.setMessage("No SP found");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum30) {
            getKey4 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key4", plus30);
            bar4.setText(getKey4);
        } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum30) {
            getKey5 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key5", minus30);
            bar4.setText(getKey5);
        } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum30) {
            getKey6 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key6", percentageActual30);
            bar4.setText(getKey6);
        }
    }
    if (spinnerSelection == null || spinnerSelection2 == null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
        builder.setTitle("Data Input Error");
        builder.setMessage("No SP found");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S2") && spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
        if (actualshippersnum == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
            builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
            builder.setMessage("No SP found");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum20) {
            getKey7 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key7", plus20);
            bar5.setText(getKey7);
        } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum20) {
            getKey8 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key8", minus20);
            bar4.setText(getKey8);
        } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum20) {
            getKey9 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key9", percentageActual20);
            bar4.setText(getKey9);
        }
    } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S2") && spinnerSelection2.equals("30")) {
        if (actualshippersnum == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
            builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
            builder.setMessage("No SP found");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum30) {
            getKey10 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key10", plus30);
            bar4.setText(getKey10);
        } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum30) {
            getKey11 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key11", minus30);
            bar4.setText(getKey11);
        } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum30) {
            getKey12 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key12", percentageActual30);
            bar4.setText(getKey12);
        }
    }
        if (spinnerSelection == null || spinnerSelection2 == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
            builder.setTitle("Data Input Error");
            builder.setMessage("Line S3 Data has not been entered yet!");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else if (spinnerSelection.equals("S3")) {
            if (spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
                //HAVENT FILLED INTO DECOVIEW - 20
                if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                    builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum20) {
                    getKey13 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key13", plus20);
                    bar6.setText(getKey13);
                } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum20) {
                    getKey14 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key14", minus20);
                    bar6.setText(getKey14);
                } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum20) {
                    getKey15 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key15", percentageActual20);
                    bar6.setText(getKey15);
                }
            } else if (spinnerSelection2.equals("30")) {

                //HAVENT FILLED INTO DECOVIEW - 30
                if (actualshippersnum == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Refresh Error");
                    builder.setMessage("Cannot Refresh! Please Fill in Line Details");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else if (actualshippersnum > optimum30) {
                    getKey16 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key16", plus30);
                    bar6.setText(getKey16);
                } else if (actualshippersnum < optimum30) {
                    getKey17 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key17", minus30);
                    bar6.setText(getKey17);
                } else if (actualshippersnum == optimum30) {
                    getKey18 = sharedPreferences.getInt("Key18", percentageActual30);
                    bar6.setText(getKey18);
```

Comment: It will be easier do help if you post some code.

Comment: that should work, but you should check if your sharedpreference key is has a value or not, by checking if it's empty else not if it's a string. Fetch the values from onCreate and onResume (incase of onbackpressed from second activity) before setting it to textview

Comment: I have added code :)

Comment: @MaciejBiałorucki

Comment: @Roljhon is that the way I am doing it>>

Comment: I think that you should call apply() or commit() on editor object in Line Details activity.

Comment: @Rajeey3, Maciej is right, you forgot the to apply your changes to the editor see his answer above. If you're coding in android studio, always watch out with the warnings, it tells you exactly what you should do or what you're lacking

Comment: do I need to apply or commit after each possible putint? or just at the end

Comment: @Rajeey3 not sure how exactly your if statements work, to avoid further issues, just do what you're thinking or in every if/else block

Comment: will give it a try.. thanks! will let you know the outcome

Comment: No still receiving nulls at startup and also crashing once returning to dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can override onActivityResult method in "Dashboard" and get result from "Line Details" activity. 
[Follow this link for more info](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: so should I be using intents instead?? would that still return null though if my dashboard is the first screen shown?

Comment: You can use SharedPreference also. If your dashboard is opened first time then you can get the default values from shared preferences. Then when you open details page, save all data in shared preference and call setResult(RESULT_OK). Now when details activity is closed you will get a callback in our overridden onActivtyResult method in the dashboard activity. From there you can refresh the views. So the problem of automatic view update will be solved.

Comment: This sounds promising, although I am quite unsure of which code goes where? also it is because I need to repeat the IF statements in the dashboard to decide whether the line is behind ahead or on target that I am receving nulls @srs